# How to apply Boolean functions in ngStyle

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

```
<div *ngFor= “ let singleorder of order.order”>
    <p [ngStyle]="
      'color':(single order.status === 'CONFIRM' )? 'green' : 'red' ,
       'background' : (single order.status === 'CONFIRM')? '#e4f4eb': '#f7d0c7'
    }">. {{single order.status}}>

</div>
```

I am expecting the background color and color to be green when the value of status is CONFIRM and also show red when the value is CANCELLED

Comment: have you tried using ngClass ?

Comment: I suggest you show the component files: HTML, CSS and TS in order to help you better

Comment: I have edited it kindly help

Comment: What is the `single` doing there? That doesn't look valid.

Comment: the singleorder is from a for loop

Comment: It doesn't say `singleorder` though. It says `single order`.

Comment: Also, you have so-called "smart quotes" in your code. That won't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the [documentation](https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle), this is the correct syntax (note the curly braces).

```
<p [ngStyle]="{
  'color': singleorder.status === 'CONFIRM' ? 'green' : 'red',
  'background': singleorder.status === 'CONFIRM' ? '#e4f4eb': '#f7d0c7'
}">
  {{singleorder.status}}>
</p>
```

Since you're basing multiple style properties on the same condition, it would probably be cleaner to define a couple of CSS classes and use [`ngClass`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass) or use [class binding](https://angular.io/guide/class-binding).